# Pop Out an image for a facebook application

Tags: php, html, facebook, application-server

i have a facebook application framework that just renders an image from a web server . i use the img src tag to render the image .

the image gets displayed in a small rectangular region of the facebook screen . i would like the image to pop-out to cover the users window screen . so that its the only image he views as of that moment . How can i do that ? do i need to use html tags . which ones do you suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/).

```
$(document).ready(init)
{
    var options = {};
    options.href = "http://url-to-your-image.com";
    options.width = "100%";
    options.height = "100%";

    $.colorbox( options ); 
}
```

Comment: hi chuck . i do realise that the colorbix widget might help. However being new could you also please guide me as to how to use it ? i mean where should i place the files on the web servers same directory as my index.php file ?

Comment: @sumeet who is chuck? Anyway, i suggest that you download the examples on the colorbox page, and do a view source on them to see what files they're including and how, that should help you.